# printing to excel file, python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

```
import csv
from math import sqrt
import os

class MaxiAverageCalculator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ncols = 3
        self.nrows = 0
        self.s = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        self.s2 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

    def run(self, fullpath):
        with open(fullpath, "rb") as infile:
            reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=",")
            self.colnames = list(next(reader))
            assert len(self.colnames) == 3
            for row in reader:
                L = [ float(x) for x in row ]
                assert len(L) == 3
                for i, x in enumerate(L):
                    self.s[i] += x
                    self.s2[i] += x * x
                self.nrows += 1
        self.avg = [x/self.nrows for x in self.s]
        self.std = [ sqrt((y/self.nrows) - a * a) for a, y in zip(self.avg, self.s2) ]
        print "Results for {0}".format(fullpath)
        for name, a, s in zip(self.colnames, self.avg, self.std):
            f.write(str(a))
            f.write(", ")
            f.write(str(s))

        f.write("\n")
##            print "{0}: avg = {1:.5f}, std = {2:.5f}".format(name, a, s)
##        print

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path="A:\\yoyo\\heyy\\folder"
    f=open("A\\yoy\\save.xls")
    f.write("xavg, xstd, yavg, ystd, zavg, zstd")
    f.write("\n")
    dirList=os.listdir(path)
    for file in dirList:
        fullpath=os.path.join(path,file)
        calc = MaxiAverageCalculator()
        calc.run(fullpath)
```

so im trying to print the avg and std for x, y, and z on a separate excel file...i got this script online. but it doesn't seem to work...please help

Comment: "i got this script online. but it doesn't seem to work" Do you have any understanding of what it's supposed to do? This site is for people who write programs, not for people who just want to run them.

Comment: @Temesgen Abba: you could post how you figured it out as an answer and accept it, that would help any user looking for an answer here

Answer (score 1):

You still work with flopy disks? Wow :-)
Nevertheless, in one path you write `"A:\\..."`, in the other `"A\\..."`. Maybe that's it.

Besides, you should explicitly pass `f` to `run()`. It is better style.

Comment: its not that...s i want it to print xavg, xstd, yavg, ystd, zavg, zstd....but when i run the script, this is how it prints xavg, xstd, ystd, zstd.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
for name, a, s in zip(self.colnames, self.avg, self.std):
        f.write(str(a))
        f.write(", ")
        f.write(str(s))
```

You aren't separating the previous standard deviation from the next average by a comma or new line in the loop. So suppose your averages are [10, 20, 30] and standard deviations [1, 2, 3]. What gets written into the file will be:

10, 120, 230, 3

If you want it to be:

10, 1, 20, 2, 30, 3

then I'd say a bit of extra code (this might not be the best way to do it but it works):

```
count = 0
for name, a, s in zip(self.colnames, self.avg, self.std):
        count += 1
        f.write(str(a))
        f.write(", ")
        f.write(str(s))
        if count < len(self.avg):    # If it is not the last record
            f.write(", ")            # Add a comma separating the std from the next avg
```

Also why are you zipping the column names at all in the loop? You aren't using it anywhere.